# Split on space ignore if inside quotes using regex / Java code

Tags: java, regex

I have two string like below..I want to split those string on space but ignore space if space found inside quotes....

```
LA    L'TL0BPC,C'ABC  '   THIS IS COMMENT
LA    C'TL0PC',C'ABC  '   THIS IS COMMENT
MVC   EBW000(4),=C'MPI '  THIS IS ANOTHER' CASE
```

I want to split those lines like this

`LA` `L'TL0BPC,C'ABC  '` `THIS` `IS` `COMMENT`

`LA`    `C'TL0PC',C'ABC  '`  `THIS` `IS` `COMMENT`

How to achieve this using java regex....Any other solution is also acceptable..

I have tried this:

```
String ODD_QT_REGEX="[ ]+(?=([^'']*'[^'']*')*[^'']*)"; 
String EVEN_QT_REGEX="[ ]+(?=([^'']*'[^'']*')*[^'']*$)";
```

but this doesn't do what I need.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: String ODD_QT_REGEX="[ ]+(?=([^'']*'[^'']*')*[^'']*)";       
String EVEN_QT_REGEX="[ ]+(?=([^'']*'[^'']*')*[^'']*$)";
I tried with this two ...but its failing......

Comment: Why did you post it as comment? Your attempts should be part of your question. So use [edit] option to place it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do matching instead of splitting. Splitting according to this `"[ ]+(?=([^'']*'[^'']*')*[^'']*)";` regex is possible only if your input has balanced quotes.

Seems like i figured out the problem. Same like the op's regex but this regex won't consider an apostrophe as a single quote.  The below regex would match one or more space characters which is followed by

- `\b'\b` An apostrophe.
- `|` OR
- `'[^']'` single quote block.
- `|` OR
- `[^']` Any character but not of single quote.
- `(?:\\b'\\b|'[^']*'|[^'])*`, zero or more times. Then it must be followed by an end of the line anchor.

**Code:**

```
String r = "LA    L'TL0BPC,C'ABC  '  THIS IS COMMENT";
String[] m = r.split("\\s+(?=(?:\\b'\\b|'[^']*'|[^'])*$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));
```

**OR**

For more exact case, you could replace `\b` in the above regex with lookarounds.

```
"\\s+(?=(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[A-Za-z])|'[^']*'|[^'])*$)"
```

**Output:**

```
[LA, L'TL0BPC,C'ABC  ', THIS, IS, COMMENT]
```

Comment: The unbalanced quote threw me off!

Comment: Doing some testing.....If passed i will accept your ans...and +1 for explanation...

Comment: EMPAS870 EQU   *               >>> TOP OF 'RESTACK THE INELIGIBLES LOOP..Any correction possible for this line???its not splitting on space before quote...

Comment: no, because there is only one single quote present and it's not an apostrophe.

Comment: MVC   EBW000(4),=C'MPI '  TELL EMQ4 TO PROCESS COMP NRFN'S this one also failing...Plz help.....

Comment: @anupammaiti may i know the logic of splitting? How it would split according to the spaces which are outside the single quotes where the input string contain exactly one quote?